# How to create a Linq query to check if data exists in the database?

Tags: asp.net, json, linq

The problem that I'm having is I can't get the query to check to see if the same text already exists in the same attribute within the database.
Below is the part of the controller. This query contains if statement.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostBook(Booking bookings, string Title)
    {
        if(!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var SearchData = await _context.bookings.Where(x => x.Title == Title).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
            if (SearchData != null) 
                return BadRequest("bad request");
        }


        _context.bookings.Add(bookings);
         _context.SaveChanges();


        return Ok();
    }
```

Whenever I input the same data it comes out as either 200 requests or 500 internal error. The expected outcome should be a 400 bad request. When I make a Post request from postman 400 bad request should appear. This is similar to checking if a username already exists. What I'm trying to implement is a restaurant reservation system that won't allow users to have the same name or time? How can you do this for Time with hourly based sessions and string? 
I'm wondering if any of you guys have done this before checking if the same value or text exists within the database.

I'm using .net core with vs code and Postman to post the JSON data.

below is my model for the booking model.

```
    public class Booking
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }

        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        public string Request { get; set; }

        public int NoPeople { get; set; }

        public Customer Customer { get; set;}

}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you're only searching for existing bookings when the modelstate is not valid? That code will never get hit if you're posting valid data, which would explain why you never see the 400 Bad Request

Answer (score 0):

Issue is that value used to check for uniqueness is different than value saved to the database.

Remove `Title` parameter and use title property from booking instance to check for uniqueness.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostBook(Booking newBooking)
{
    var titleExists = 
        await _context.bookings.AnyAsync(b => b.Title == newBooking.Title);

    if (titleExists) 
        return BadRequest($"Title '{newBooking.Title}' already exists");
    }

    _context.bookings.Add(newBooking);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Ok();
}
```

With `AnyAsync` function you can check for existence without loading whole record in case such record exists.

Comment: Brilliant thanks that actually worked. I've been struggling for this about two weeks but now it works thank you Fabio.